# RegistroResponse.getErrorCode()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webservice

Estoy haciendo un login para una aplicacion movil, ya hice el signup y funciona a la perfeccion, pero a la hora de hacer login me dice que el errorCode que me retorna el webService es nulo, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal o si es algo del WebService, estoy comparando con el de signup y es lo mas parecido posible, no se cual sea el problema.

Este método es para mandar a llamar el WebService las variables están bien y no da ningún error de código, lo que ocurre es que crashea.

```
public void postLogin(String username, String pass){
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Cargando");
    dialog.show();
    apiService = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    LoginBody body = null;
    try {
        body = new LoginBody(
                ""+username,
                ""+pass
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String json = new Gson().toJson(body);
    Log.i("bodyRes", json+"");

    Call<RegistroResponse> callT = apiService.getLoginUsuarioApp(body);

    callT.enqueue(new Callback<RegistroResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RegistroResponse> call, @NotNull retrofit2.Response<RegistroResponse> response) {
            final RegistroResponse Res = response.body();

            String json = new Gson().toJson(Res);
            Log.i("bodyRES", json + "");

            assert Res != null;
            if( Res.getErrorCode() == 0){

                Registro r = (Registro) Res.getMsg();

                registrodb.deleteAll();
                userdb.deleteAll();
                registrodb.insert(r);
                userdb.insert(r.getUserData().get(0));

                startMainActivity();

            }else if(Res.getErrorCode() == 2){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Datos Incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull final Call<RegistroResponse> call, final Throwable t) {
            if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                //onError();
                Log.e("Error",""+t);
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa esta línea: `assert Res != null;`?

Comment: Esa linea me la aconsejo Android Studio para supuestamente evitar el valor nulo pero siempre me lo tira

Comment: Es una asignación extraña, prueba a comentarla. Y revisa el log para ver si `json` es correcto. Generalmente cuando trabajas con json se usa un bloque `try ... catch`.

Comment: Ya lo hice, el json si lo envia como se debe pero me da esto en el log

bodyRES: null

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes que revisar es la respuesta que te está dando la API, parece que te está devolviendo `NULL`.

Comment: ¿el Res tiene informacion? ¿visto si realmente retorna algo?  al obligar que sea distinto de nulo como verificacion  omite lo que sigue, es posible que este retonarno un null o un vacio desde tu response y por ello levanta un throw.
Como recomendacion podrias omitir el assert e ingresar lo que prosigue del codigo en try/catch asi el *studio* no te hara la sugerencia por una posible referencia nula